# Symmetries and Dirac Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, dirac-equation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

For spacetime translation given by

> Under spacetime translations the spinor transforms as
>   $$\delta\psi=\epsilon^\mu\partial_\mu\psi$$
>   The Lagrangian depends on $\partial_\mu\psi$, but not $\partial_\mu\bar{\psi}$, so the standard formula gives us the energy-momentum tensor
>   $$T^{\mu\nu}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$
>   Since a current is conserved only when the equations of motion are obeyed, we don't lose anything by imposing the equations of motion already on $T^{\mu\nu}$. In the case of a scalar field this didn't really buy us anything because the equations of motion are second order in derivatives, while the energy-momentum is typically first order: $(i\partial\!\!\!/-m)\psi=0$. This means we can set $\mathcal{L}=0$ in $T^{\mu\nu}$, leaving
>   $$T^{\mu\nu}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi$$

As quoted by David Tong 'For a spinor field the equation of motion are first order. This means we can set $L=0$ in $T^{μν}$ tensor'. How does a first order equation of motion make $L=0$? http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html (page 18)( 4.6 Symmetries and Conserved Currents)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please click this link if the image is not proparly uploaded  http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/four.pdf   (page 18)( 4.6 Symmetries and Conserved Currents). My question is how can we show that under spacetime translation L=0?

Comment: You should write out your own question, rather than just posting a picture.

Comment: My question is how can we show that under spacetime translation L=0 (L is dirac lagrangian) in Tμν tensor equation?

Comment: Under spacetime translations the change is the Lagrangian is NOT zero, it equals $\epsilon_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}L$. That's why there is a term involving the Lagrangian in the energy momentum tensor.

Comment: Yes , I agree with you. But as quoted by david tong 'For a spinor field the equation of motion are first order. This means we can set L=0 in Tμν tensor'. How does a first order equation of motion makes L=0?  damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/four.pdf (page 18)( 4.6 Symmetries and Conserved Currents)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't understand it at first. So basically the conservation of the Noether current (which is the energy momentum tensor in this case) is only true on-shell. If yiu carefully check the derivation of the Noether current you'll see that the equations of motion have been used. Hence we can use the EOM in the expression for the EM tensor and since the Lagrangian basically is $bar(\psi)$(EOM)$\psi$, we can take it to ne zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SounakSinha . Can you please tell me why cant we use the same trick, had the equations of motion being second order?

Comment: We can't use the same trick for, say a KG field because the Lagrangian you use to derive the EM tensor isn't of the required form, $\phi$(EOM)$\phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point, if I understand correctly, is that since $\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi} (i \not \partial - m) \psi$ and $(i \not \partial - m) \psi = 0$ from the equations of motion, the equations of motion imply $\mathcal{L} = 0$. The fact that $\mathcal{L}$ is of first order is what makes this possible, because the equations of motion *can* be equal to the Lagrangian, but I don't think it's a sufficient condition. Consider something like this:

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi} \overleftarrow{\not \partial} (i \not \partial - m) \psi,$$

where the arrow means that the derivative acts on the left. The EOM are

$$ \not\partial (i \not \partial - m) \psi = 0,$$

which don't imply $\mathcal{L} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated explanation.

Comment: +1. Maybe I'm being silly, but isn't that Lagrangian equal, up to a total derivative, to the same expression but with the leftmost derivative acting to the right? The latter expression would be conserved. Also, regardless, the equation of motion from the Lagrangian is second order.